# error C2137 : Empty character constant in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, warnings, compiler-warnings

Here is the code :

```
void SomeClass::SomeFunctionToCorrectName(CString &strName)
{
        
    //  Only alphabets (Aa-Zz), numbers(0-9), "_" (underscore) and "-" (hyphen) are allowed. 
                
        for(int nIndex = 0; nIndex < strName.GetLength(); nIndex++)
        {
            TCHAR currentChar = strName.GetAt(nIndex);
            
            if((currentChar >= _T('a') && currentChar <= _T('z')) ||
                (currentChar >= _T('A') && currentChar <= _T('Z')) ||
                (currentChar >= _T('0') && currentChar <= _T('9')) ||
                currentChar == _T('-') || currentChar == _T('_'))
            {
                continue;
            }
            strName.Replace(currentChar,_T(''));    
        }
}
```

This method removes anything extra in `strName` and only alphabets (Aa-Zz), numbers(0-9), "_" (underscore) and "-" (hyphen) are allowed. The if cases are to check those allowed conditions.
If its not under the allowed conditions it will remove that.

```
For Eg desired i/p :"Hel*lo*World" and desired o/p : "HelloWorld"
```

But the following gives me error as follows :

```
error C2137: empty character constant

I can fix this error by using any of the three methods:
1. using '\0'
2. using ' ' (space in between ' ')
3. using ""[0]
```

but this introduces space while replacing.

```
Input :Hel*lo*World
Output :Hel lo World
Desired Output :HelloWorld
```

Can anyone suggest how can I get the desired result?

Comment: Note: a-z, A-Z are not guarantied to be consecutive in C++ (as EBCDIC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *remove* a specific character, then `Replace` is not the right method to use. As you've noticed, there is nothing reasonable to replace the character with.

Instead you can use `Remove` like this:

```
strName.Remove(currentChar);
```

Comment: Then have to fix index incrementation, and so go to erase-remove idiom :)

Comment: @MALLASARJSULEBHANVI Good :) But Jarod42 makes a good point. I didn't really look at the rest of the loop. Make sure that `nIndex` is the value you need it to be.

Comment: @cigien Okay, Here, I want to iterate through all the characters and remove which are not alphabets, digits ,'-' or '_' . Once I am remove a invalid character, I am incrementing to a next character. But I don't get a problem here in this case. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm not saying there *is* a problem :) I'm just saying that I answered your question by only looking at the line you mentioned, and didn't pay any attention to how it interacts with the loop. If you don't have a problem with it, that's great :)

Comment: @MALLASARJSULEBHANVI: you should have issue with consecutive (different) characters to remove.

Comment: Yeah you are correct @Jarod42 . I am looking into it.

Comment: Following changes in the counter decrement fixes it  :
`int sizeL = strName.size();`
`for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < sizeL; nIndex++)`
        `strName.erase(nIndex, 1);`
       `sizeL--;`
        `nIndex--;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string someFunctionToCorrectName(std::string &strName)
{
    for(int nIndex = 0; nIndex < strName.size(); nIndex++)
    {
            char currentChar = strName[nIndex];
            if (
                (currentChar >= 'a' && currentChar <= 'z') ||
                (currentChar >= 'A' && currentChar <= 'Z') ||
                (currentChar >= '0' && currentChar <= '9') ||
                currentChar == '-' || currentChar == '_')
            {
                continue;
            }
            strName.erase(nIndex, 1);    
    }
    return strName;
}

int main() {
    std::string str("Hel*lo*World");
    std::cout << someFunctionToCorrectName(str) << "\n"; //==> HelloWorld
    return 0;
}
```